# Expected type 'SupportsIndex | slice', got 'str' instead

Tags: python, arrays

```
protocols = [[['TCP'['Transmission Control Protocol']], ['UDP'["User Protocol"]], ['HTTP'["Hypertext Transfer Protocol"]], ['HTTPS'["Hypertext Transfer Protocol Secure"]]]]
print(protocols)
```

Hello I am new to python and when I try to print this array to screen and it comes up with error that I have put as the title sorry if this was supposed to be easy but I am new to python thank you any help

Comment: Brackets `[]` are about lists and indexing, and as the error message says, indexing a string with another string (like when you write `'TCP'['Transmissin Control Protocol']`) won't work. But I guess that's not what you wanted anyway, so what was the actual intent here?

Comment: What's `[['TCP'['Transmission Control Protocol']]` suppose to be? I think you want a `dict`? `protocols = {'TCP': 'Transmission Control Protocol', 'UDP': "User Protocol",...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you wish to create a list of protocols -  name and description
look at following:

P.S. UDP -  User Datagram Protocol

```
protocols = [
    ['TCP', 'Transmission Control Protocol'],
    ['UDP', 'User Datagram Protocol'], 
    ['HTTP', 'Hypertext Transfer Protocol'],
    ['HTTPS', 'Hypertext Transfer Protocol Secure']
]

print(protocols)
```

Comment: That's a bad idea. `dict` will be much more appropriate here.

Comment: If you have a more effective solution, please consider sharing it to assist the person asking, rather than posting comments that may not be constructive

Comment: I posted in the comments since it's unclear what the OP is trying to do. You answer is to create a protocol and description, a classic case to use a dictionary that won't require to filter a list of lists every time.